# Changing sheetstyle by culture

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net themes and want to change the sheet style within the same theme when the user change his culture.
Is there any way to do this?
Knowing that I am using theme Selector control that taking all themes in App_Theme folder as a datasource and do not want to repeat themes for each culture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the whole theme, you can override the `StyleSheetTheme` property in the `Page`:

```
public override String StyleSheetTheme
{
    get 
    { 
        string theme = "";

        switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
        {
            case "en-US":
                theme = "YourTheme1"; break;
            case "nl-NL":
                theme = "YourTheme2"; break;
        }
        return theme;
    }
}
```

More information here:

[How to: Apply ASP.NET Themes Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

If you want to change just the CSS:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string css = "";
    switch (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
    {
        case "en-US":
            css = "YourCSS1"; break;
        case "nl-NL":
            css = "YourCSS2"; break;
    }

    HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
    cssLink.Href = string.Format("CSS/{0}.css", css);
    cssLink.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
    cssLink.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
    cssLink.Attributes["media"] = "all";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
}
```

Comment: I do not want to change the theme, This require to make theme1.en-us and theme1.fr-fr then all repeated theme will shown in my theme selector control